# Issue with £ character on windows, mac and linux with a ruby script

Tags: ruby, encoding

I have a team of 3 people working on a project. We are all using windows 7 for development and some of have ruby 1.8.7 and some 1.9.2.

two fo us are exclusively using Aptana Studio, while one of us is using Eclipse.

I keep having an issue with a .rb file that has the £ in it where a unicode character at the beginning of the file causes the ruby parser on my machine to give up on the file with an error.

If I open the file in notepad++ I can change the encoding so it works on my machine, but then it doesn't work on the linux (RHEL) server. I can change the encoding (again) so it works on my dev machine and the server, but then it breaks on my Mac OS X again.

Any ideas what's going on?

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have unicode in your code, you need to enable it in ruby 1.9.2 with a "magic comment"

```
   # encoding: UTF-8
```

Put this near the top of your code.

Comment: If you have 1.8.7 you should not need that.  What error are you getting?

Comment: Also if you put the magic comment in, it will not affect ruby 1.8.7 so it makes sense to add it if you are running 1.9 environments.